# Deserializing a json object using gson only on certain fields

Tags: java, json, gson

If I have a class say

```
class A
{
String field1
String field2
String field3
}
```

And I have another class B that contains the following

```
{
String field1
String field2
}
```

There is a byte array of key value pairs, [#maps to field1, #maps to field2] How can I using gson map the byte array to the fields in class A without creating a class B that contains the exact number of fields in the map ?

Can I exclude field3 while deserialization ? How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to mark `field3` as

> transient

Gson will not populate (deserialize) its value from the string..
Alternatively, you can use a custom deserializer implementation which would selectively deserialize things. Here is a [link](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) for this kind of solution.